# Debian's bug with repo

Tags: debian, repository

Who uses debian servers (8, 9), do you have everything right now with official repositories? Previously, everything worked without problems, and then massively, suddenly on all servers and desktops such a problem manifested itself! I can not connect to them and update / install anything with the following errors:
**The repository 'http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable Release' does not have a Release file.
Failed to fetch http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/stable-updates/non-free/source/Sources  403  Forbidden**

Also I tried to change repositories, but errors are the same!

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved just after rebooting host server, as I see, this an another one bug of OpenVZ! Rebooting of his virtual machines didn't help.